# How to instantiate a new object of LoginData inside CreateLoginAsync() without errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

This code have not errors now. But I'm trying to connect with the api and in the `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync"login/", login);`the page charges infinitely and the console shows me this: El `programa '[672] iisexpress.exe' terminó con código -1 (0xffffffff).`
I have verified that it is not a problem of the server, since in that case, it should receive a code 404. But instead the page remains loading indefinitely.

The Code:

```
 namespace Vaersacces
 {
//Plantilla para datos del Login
public class LoginData
{
    string user;
    string pass;

    public LoginData(string user, string pass)
    {
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
    }

}

//Clase Asíncrona para llamar al Web Service 
public class AsyncTaskLogin
{

    //Instancia de un nuevo cliente
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    //Se asignan los datos a la nueva instancia
    public static async Task<Uri> RunAsync(LoginData login)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("dirección del servidor");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        //Respuesta del servidor
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Entrando en CreateLoginAsync");
        Uri uri = await CreateLoginAsync(login);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Saliendo de CreateLoginAsync");
        return uri;
    }   

    //Método para postear un objeto tipo LoginData en formato Json
    public static async Task<Uri> CreateLoginAsync(LoginData login)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
            "login/", login);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return response.Headers.Location;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: "You must to reference the object." Is that the actual error message? Please cut and paste the actual message and indicate which line causes the error.

Comment: "An object's reference for the non-static field, method or 'AsyncTaskLogin.user' property is required"

Comment: Think you need to remove the `static` keyword from the declaration of `CreateLoginAsync()`. Did you have a good reason to make it static?

Comment: If I do that, the error is taken to "await CreateLoginAsync()" D:

Comment: `user` and `pass` aren't static you can't access them from a static method. why is that method static anyway. and exactly what error do you get when you make it not static.

Comment: Exactly the same error but refered to CreateLoginAsync() in the part of the previous method: Uri uri = await CreateLoginAsync().

Comment: `Uri uri = await CreateLoginAsync()` is not in the posted code, can you edit that method in.

Comment: If the next method up the chain is static as well, you'll have to change that one too.

Comment: If you use parameters instead of member-fields, you could avoid this problem, I think. Can you show the code, where CreateLoginAsync is awaited?

Comment: Now it's running, but I have a new problem. I have updated the post in case you know what could be happening.

Comment: If your issue is solved, and as you mentioned it is. You should open a new question for your new issue. Furthermore the Errormessages of IE are not really useful, could you test with another browser instead and add the error-message?